# How to create an bootable .iso file from Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: live-usb, iso

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB (32 GB).

- Is it possible to create a *bootable* **.iso** file from the Live USB ?

*how can I create a bootable ISO?*

Comment: Is the second point actually how to clone an existing live USB? Do you need to cache the files as copies on disk first or is a direct copy to a new USB medium ok as well?

Comment: @ByteCommander clone?? you mean duplicate ..then No.And  "cache the files as copies on disk first " ...yes =)

Answer (score 9):

It should be enough to just `cat` the device. If your USB is, for example, `/dev/sdb`, you can do:

```
cat /dev/sdb > foo.img
```

to restore the image to a USB disk, do:

```
cat foo.img > /dev/sdb
```

Note that this approach will create an image file as large as the drive itself, even if the drive is almost empty. If the drive is not 100% full and you only want an iso of the used space, use `genisoimage` (install it with `apt install genisoimage`) instead:

```
genisoimage -o foo.iso /path/to/usb/mount/point
```

Comment: In case of 2 USB's 1 `dd` should be enough :D

Comment: @terdon thanks =)...my second one?...I will edit for clarity..

Comment: @Ravan see updated answer. I don't see why you would want to do that though. Just save the iso and keep that.

Comment: thanks..but in second one I don't want to  create iso at all...directly again live usb...no concept of iso

Comment: What if the USB stick is much larger than the image needs, e.g. 8GB. Will the `.iso` file then be 8GB in size with much blank space in it or will it only eat up as much as necessary to hold the data? I'm referring to both the `cat` and the `genisoimage` methods.

Comment: @ByteCommander good point. The `cat` approach will indeed make a file as large as the device, irrespective of how much data you have. The `geniso` will make a file only as big as the used space of the device. Thanks, answer edited.

Comment: What about dd command?

Comment: @terdon please see my edit

Comment: @Ravan sorry, don't know about that. You might want to ask a new question. Make sure you try this first though, I'm not sure if the header is as important as you say.

Comment: @Raphael what about it? It's not needed here.

Comment: I think genisoimage may be dead. To shrink the image file greatly, consider something like sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=16M conv=sync,noerror | pv | sudo pigz -c > /media/drive/Image.dd.gz.

Comment: @RayWoodcock why dd instead of cat?

Comment: I was influenced by Hacker News (2017): "When you use cat, it makes some decisions for you. Most of the time makes good choices but it happens to make not so optimal choices for working with large files being written to other devices or file systems." Source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13349475. Not that that's authoritative. It just seemed that dd with a healthy BS could approximate cat's speed with possibly greater precision.

Comment: @RayWoodcock there's a nice Q&A on this over at [unix.se]: [dd vs cat -- is dd still relevant these days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12538)

Comment: @terdon That discussion did shape my inclination toward dd: (1) Although the chief answer claimed that dd was "pretty much useless" as a system tool, I wasn't sure that the other answers supported that. For instance, LawrenceC's answer favored dd over cat for backing up a boot sector, which was of interest for my purposes. (2) The link in the question didn't establish a consistent cat speed advantage. (3) I still might have gone with cat, but I didn't find clear guidance on syntax. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/18/vmware-v2p/#Imaging (further suggestions welcome).

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool called **Pinguy Builder** which creates `.iso` from within the operating system.

*Pinguy Builder*  will create an installable ISO of your current system.

You can burn this ISO to an USB drive or write it directly to a DVD.
The DVD/USB is bootable and so can then be booted from any PC.

Depending on what option you choose you can determine what type of ISO will be created.

If you pick “Dist”, it backups the whole system but excludes your home folder.

If you pick “Backup”, it backups the system and will include your home folder.

References :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/

[How to launch Pinguy Builder on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682430/how-to-launch-pinguy-builder-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I did not have good luck with Pinguy. Not sure if it is being maintained. See https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/07/22/pinguy/

Answer (score 0):

At this date, [your tools](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/2021/08/17/linux-v2p/) for creating a bootable ISO in Linux include Systemback, Clonezilla, Distroshare, and possibly a few paid alternatives that I have not tried (e.g., TeraByte, PowerISO). I am [still hoping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358626/why-cant-dd-create-a-bootable-iso-from-an-ubuntu-vm) to find a way to do it with *dd*.

There are many detailed tutorials for the ISO process in Systemback and Clonezilla. I have found Systemback much more user-friendly. It has been forked within the past year or two, and even the older version works for me on Ubuntu 21.04. But Clonezilla seems to be much more enduring and widely known. You may want to try a few different tools and see which works best for you, or at least view a few different tutorials.