# How to launch Pinguy Builder on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I installed [Pinguy builder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/).

The problem is that I am able to launch it only from terminal.
In dash pinguy builder is present but when I click on `Launch` it doesn't start.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch it from dash you have to install `gksu`.

```
        sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Now you can launch PinguyBuilder from dash.